# Cartthrob - setting up hooks

Tags: cartthrob

May be a stupid question, but I just can't seem to find any documentation on it.

How do I set up a hook in cartthrob? I need to do some special calculations on the tax.

I tried

```
ee()->cartthrob->core->hooks->set_hook("cart_tax_end");
public function cart_tax_end($tax) {
    return 200;
}
```

But that didn't seem to do anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CT's hooks work in the same way as native EE hooks. This means that you need to create an extension to use them: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extensions.html

HOWEVER, depending on your exact requirements, it may be best to create a Cartthrob tax plugin: http://cartthrob.com/docs/developers/tax_plugins/index.html

Comment: I tried that but Hook is not even calling. Am I missing something?